# Nested loop breaking

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

There is the following Angular/CoffeeScript function:

```
User.prototype.hasPermissions = ->
  result = false
  angular.forEach this.scopes, (scope) ->
    angular.forEach scope, (permission) ->
      result = true if permission
  result
```

It works good, but this function has some overhead - it continues working till the last item. But I need to return from hasPermissions when nested loop (for permissions) finds the first 'true' value; although this function must return false. I tried to do the following one:

```
User.prototype.hasPermissions = ->
  angular.forEach this.scopes, (scope) ->
    angular.forEach scope, (permission) ->
      return true if permission
  false
```

It doesn't work. Please, help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide what is `scopes` and `scope` type?

Comment: Place condition (!result) on the inner loop.

Comment: see this [issue#9797](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9797)

Answer (score 0):

`return` will not work, because it returns from lambda which is bypassed to `forEach` as second argument. You shouldn't use `forEach` here. In CoffeScript you can just write something like:

```
for scope in this.scopes
  for permission in scope
    return true if permission
```